# Do I need to reset a Perl hash index?

Tags: perl, hash

OK, this is a N00b question, but it's gotten me stumped:

I have the following Perl code:

```
%project_keys = (
  cd     => "continuous_delivery",
  cm     => "customer_management",
  dem    => "demand",
  dis    => "dis",
  do     => "devops",
  sel    => "selection",
  seo    => "seo"
);

print "proj_code is $proj_code\n";
while ( ($key, $value) = each %project_keys ) {
    if ($key == $proj_code) {
        $url = "http://projects/".$project_keys{$key}."/setter";
        last;
    }
}
```

`$proj_code` is always passed in the same `('dis')` and the print line shows that.

However, each time I run this, I'm getting a different value for `project_keys{$key}`.

What (no doubt obvious) thing am I doing wrong? I have seen comments about how each is 'fragile' - is that it?

Comment: Why not say: `$url = "http://projects/$project_keys{'dis'}" if exists $project_keys{'dis'};`?

Comment: Also, you should use `eq` for strings, not `==`. See [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have the "key" you're expecting, check if it exists and use it...

Also, always use `use strict; use warnings;`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $proj_code= 'dis';
my $url;

my %project_keys = (
  cd     => "continuous_delivery",
  cm     => "customer_management",
  dem    => "demand",
  dis    => "dis",
  do     => "devops",
  sel    => "selection",
  seo    => "seo"
);

$url = "http://projects/$project_keys{$proj_code}/setter" 
    if exists $project_keys{$proj_code};

print "url: $url\n";
```

OUTPUTS:

```
url: http://projects/dis/setter
```

Comment: First off, thanks. Second, what's the easiest way to concatenate the hash keys into a regex - I want to do something like this: `if ($title =~ /(cd|cm|dem|dis|do|sel|seo)(\d+)\s.*/) {` and then check the $1 rather than proj_code in my example. Basically, if the title of this review is e.g. `"cm1234 - do some DIS work"`, then I need to link it to `http://projects/customer_management/setter`. Does that make sense? The hash table will eventually come from a file, so I don't want any hard-coding in there at all...

Comment: @roryhewitt np. You should ask another question about keys to regex.  Better than combining two separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you use `each` to iterate through a hash but don't iterate all the way till no result is returned, you will pick up the next time where you left off.

You can reset the internal iterator to the beginning by using keys or values before looping, like so:

```
keys(%project_keys);
while ( ($key, $value) = each %project_keys ) {
```

That said, you have a number of other problems:

Use `eq`, not `==`, to test for string equality.

Your whole loop is pointless; you don't *need* to iterate through a hash to look up a value; the loop can be replaced with simply doing:

```
if ( exists $project_keys{$proj_code} ) {
    $url = "http://projects/$project_keys{$proj_code}";
}
```

Comment: @ysyth, Even though yours wasn't the 'accepted answer', I appreciate the additional info about using keys prior to the while loop.

Comment: [Perldoc confirms this](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html): Each hash ... has its own internal iterator, accessed by `each`... The iterator is implicitly reset when `each` has reached the end as just described; it can be explicitly reset by calling `keys` ... on the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `each`. Best not to. It's subtle and stores state within the hash.

Far better than

```
while( my ( $key, $value ) = each %hash ) {
   ...
}
```

is to use a `foreach` loop on the `keys` function

```
foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {
   my $value = $hash{$key};
   ...
}
```