# How to store regex results in Perl for building substitution strings?

Tags: regex, perl, hashtable

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22341722) for starters, but I'm not sure I need a hash table to store intermediate results. If so great, but I'm new to Perl, so unsure.

It seems like this would have to be done in a loop, to store each result in a scalar and then apply, then move to the next line. But again I'm new to this.

1. Scan lines for pattern. In this case, HTML. Yes, I know about HTML and regex, but without regex, how can I build strings dynamically from a search pattern?
2. If pattern matches, use formed string A to derive new string form B.
3. Scan lines again and substitute B for A.

In other words:

```
$stringA = 'alias="@[found by $pattern]"'
$stringB = 'alias="@[prepended string] . [found by $pattern] . [appended string]"'
```

What I have so far:

```
my $pattern = 'alias="@(.*?)"';
my %seen    = ();                 # ?

sub read_file {
  my ($file) = @_;

  open FILE, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die "Could not open '$file' for reading $!";
  local $/ = undef;

  while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /($pattern)/ ) {
      $seen{$1};                  # store results
      return $line;
    }
  }

  close FILE;
}

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper( \%seen );
```

Comment: It would be more helpful ,if you put input and expected output

Comment: It sounds like you should be asking ***"how can I build strings dynamically from a search pattern"*** first. There is no question that you need to use a proper HTML parser, and if you don't know how to do it then please ask. Also, as `@Praveen` says, please give examples of your data and the expected transformation.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to modify the values of `alias` attributes. Is that correct? If you give an example of your input XML data and explain how you want to change it then I am sure you will get much better help.

Comment: I thought $stringA and $stringB were sufficient, but point taken. Yes HTML is secondary to the question, but that's the type of file I'm working with. I know of HTML::Parser and will look at that.

Comment: @sqldoug: I recommend [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder), which subclasses [`HTML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Parser) and allows you to interrogate the document tree. There is also [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) which allows you to address the data structure using XPath expressions, if you are comfortable with that.

Comment: Thanks, Borodin. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
$line =~ s/($pattern)/ transform($1) /eg;
```

where `transform($1)` is the code that derives B from A (`$1`).

---

As for a non-regex solution, XPaths can be used as means of identifying HTML nodes using a language that even simpler than regex patterns.

```
my $xpath = '//@alias[starts-with(., "@")]';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_html_file($qfn);

for my $node ($doc->findnodes($xpath)) {
   transform($node);
}

$doc->toFile($qfn);
```

Comment: Thanks, ikegami. 'Transform' then is a subroutine to encapsulate that? I can work with this.

Comment: Any Perl code will do. I used a subroutine call since it conveniently abstracted the details away.

Answer (score 1):

Several comments are in the code.  Sample output is below.
Not sure if this does what you want, but hopefully something in it will help at all.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = 'alias="@(.*?)"';
my %seen    = (); # defines an empty hash

sub read_file {
    my ($file) = @_;

    # open using lexical filehandle
    open (my $fp, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
      or die "Could not open '$file' for reading $!";

    local $/ = undef; # effects 'slurp mode', that is, lets you read the entire file into one scalar.

    my $line = <$fp>;

    close ($fp); # it's all read in, so it can be safely closed here.

    # loop and use the g modifier to process every match.  
    # see the perlre man page for full discussion of modifiers
    while ( $line =~ /($pattern)/smg ) {
        $seen{$1} = 0 if (!exists ($seen{$1}));
        ++$seen{$1};
    }
}

# There was not call to read_file.  This is just a "serving suggestion:"
my $filename = $ARGV[0] || die "USAGE: $0 filename\n";
read_file ($filename);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper( \%seen );   # use 'print', not 'say'
```

I ran it with some sample data as indicated by the egrep output:

```
$ egrep '<(foo|bar)' index.html 
<foo alias="@foobar">it's foo!</foo>
<bar alias="@barfoo">it's bar!</bar>
```

And here is the result:

```
$ perl foo.pl index.html 
$VAR1 = {
          'alias="@foobar"' => 1,
          'alias="@barfoo"' => 1
        };
$
```

Comment: You should *always* use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open` in new code. Also, the first `readline` operation from a successfully-opened input file will *always* return a defined value, even if the file has zero size, so there is no need to test for it.

Comment: @Borodin, Re "the first readline operation from a successfully-opened input file will always return a defined value", That's not true. `echo -n >file ; perl -E'open my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0] or die; $_=<$fh>; say defined($_)?1:0' file` That outputs `0`, and so does the Windows equivalent.

Comment: Guess I should've tested before accepting that; @ikegami thank you.

Comment: @ikegami: I tested only with `$/` undefined, as in the OP's code, when the first readline from an empty file *does* return a null string. Try `perl -E'open my $fh, shift or die $!; local $/; say defined(<$fh>) ? 1 : 0' file`. I think the difference in behaviour constitutes a bug.